# Data get from ajax null in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am able to get the data from ajax using system.out.println. However, I am unable to pass the data to servlet. It shows null always.

Here is my jQuery:

```
      function expressCheck(number) {
            var Self=[];
            for(i=1;i<=<%=itemCodeList.size()%>;i++) Self[i-1] = document.getElementById("qtyGuestNumber_" + i).value;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ViewCategories.jsp",
                    data: {"expressData" : Self[number-1]}
                });
        };
```

Comment: do you want the ajax to be performed only once for each expressCheck call or for each item?

Comment: function expressCheck(number) {
            var Self=[];
            
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ViewCategories.jsp",
                    data: {"expressData" : Self[number-1]}
                });for(i=1;i<=<%=itemCodeList.size()%>;i++) Self[i-1] = document.getElementById("qtyGuestNumber_" + i).value;
        }; just try changing the sequence